# How to add Button after recycleview Android?

Tags: android

I would to add button after the end of recycleView.

- I have tried to add the button in xml file after recyclview but it doesn't work because reycleview consume all height of layout even though i set height: wrap content.

Everyone here can help me!

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: add a footer to your list

Comment: please post your xml layout

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/your_recylerView_id" if you are using Relative layout as a parent layout

Comment: You never heard about RelativeLayouts, did you?

Comment: I want to add the last item of recycleview that have two horizontal buttons

Comment: it doesn't work for my condition sir

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement getItemViewType in recycleView and then specify the view you like to inflate
in ur case it would be something like this

```
    @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
if (position == productPromoList?.size) {
    return 0 // inflate adapter view
  } else {
    return 1 // inflate ur button view
  }
}
```

and in ur onCreateViewHolder check the viewType and inflate ur

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    if (viewType == 0) {
      return ur adapterview
    }else (viewType == 1) {
      return ur buttonView
    }
  }
```

i am doing it like this.

Comment: make sure that you increment by one in getItemCount method otherwise ur last data will not be visible

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear layout  with vertical orientation and place the recycler view and button in that .Assign weights to recycler view and button accordingly like 4-1 respectively according to need.

Comment: In this way, it is work but it doesn't appear what I need.

Comment: I want to add button after recycleview, not display button at the end of layout.

Comment: You want your button to be adjusted according to recycler view height??

Comment: Yes, it is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set The Layout To Relative Layout.
2. In `RecyclerView` add `android:layout_above="@+id/button"`
3. In your button add  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`